# access array from ::find and add values

Tags: php, database, phalcon

I need to access data from `$newFeatured[] = games::find` and then add values `label` there.

In **Controller:**

```
 foreach ($used_games as $game_id) {

                 $newFeatured[] = games::find(array(
                        "conditions" => "id = '$game_id'",
                        "columns"    => "id, filetype "
                        ));

                 if (in_array($newFeatured->id, $new_games)) 
                  { $newFeatured->label = 'new'; }
                 else  
                  { $newFeatured->label = 'featured'; }
              }

                $this->view->newFeatured = $newFeatured;
```

`$newFeatured->id` is not working. How can I access it?

`$newFeatured->label` is also not working.

In **View** I need to access it like this.

```
foreach ($newFeatured as $hra) {

         echo $hra['0']->filetype."and".$hra['0']->label;
     }
```

Comment: print_r($newFeatured[]) see what in it?

Comment: that's a second problem. When I trying print_r or var_dump it shows every phalcon framework arrays and variables

Comment: I think its in your array of `$newFeatured[]` can you var_dump `$used_games`?

Comment: Yes. `array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "500" [1]=> string(4) "1300" }`

Comment: What is the data of `$new_games`? Can you var_dump this data?

Comment: `array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "4" [3]=> string(1) "5" [4]=> string(1) "6" }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Controller

```
    $newFeatured = array();
    foreach ($used_games as $k => $game_id) {
        $newFeatured[$k] = games::findFirst(array(
            "conditions" => "id = '$game_id'",
            "columns" => "id, filetype "
        ));

        if (in_array($newFeatured[$k]->id, $new_games)) {
            $newFeatured[$k]->label = 'new';
        } else {
            $newFeatured[$k]->label = 'featured';
        }
    }
    $this->view->newFeatured = $newFeatured;
```

ViewPage

```
    foreach ($newFeatured as $hra) {
        echo $hra->filetype . " and " . $hra->label;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You fetching the result in an array as follows:

```
$newFeatured[] = games::find(array(
                        "conditions" => "id = '$game_id'",
                        "columns"    => "id, filetype "
                        ));
```

And trying to catch **$newFeatured->id** which seems wrong to me.
Try to fetch it as simple variable (**not array**) then see what happens as follows:

```
$newFeatured = games::find(array(
                            "conditions" => "id = '$game_id'",
                            "columns"    => "id, filetype "
                            ));
```

Comment: But it is in `foreach` like this I'd get only last row from db

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ($used_games as $game_id) {
   $newFeatured[] = games::find(array(
                    "conditions" => $game_id, //returns only id coming from as $game_id of your foreach
                    "columns"    => "filetype " //this one to filetype
                    ));
      if (in_array($newFeatured['conditions'], $new_games)) 
              { $newFeatured['label'] = 'new'; }
             else  
              { $newFeatured['label'] = 'featured'; }
          }

            $this->view->newFeatured = $newFeatured;
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: conditions

Comment: Can yiou var_dump the `$newFeatured][]` before the if statement?

Comment: When I trying `print_r` or `var_dump` `$newFeatured` it shows every phalcon framework arrays and variables(thousands rows)

Comment: I see. Because you're calling the class of `games::find` so it shows every arrays.

Comment: Can you give me the `print_r($user_games)`?

Comment: You mean`$used_games`. `Array ( [0] => 500 [1] => 1300 )`